# Refrescar consulta de un JSON cada X segundos

Tags: java, android, php, json

La siguiente `Activity` obtiene los datos de un archivo en `PHP` que genera un `JSON` con los datos obtenidos de `MYSQL`, soy nuevo en esto de `JAVA ANDROID`, y tengo poca experiencia en `PHP`, apenas si me defiendo, pero estoy tratando de aprender poco a poco.

El problema de mi `Activity` es que cada vez que se refresca, la barra de desplazamiento se lanza hacia arriba, entonces lo que creo que puede resolver este problema es implementar un método que este consultando cada N segundo a travez de `JSON` en segundo plano y si detecta que el contenido de la tabla es diferente a la tabla anterior lanze el `GETDATA`, para ello me imagino muchas formas poco ortodoxas supongo, como crear una copia de a misma tabla en mysql o algo parecido y comparar los arreglos en JAVA, cosa que me es complicado por que apenas entiendo el codigo y las funcionalidades de `JAVA ANDROID`, cual quier ayuda sugerencia, comentario ya sea bueno o malos sera bien agradecido saludos.

Aqui el codigo

```
public class VerA extends ActionBarActivity {

 String myJSON;
 private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
 private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
 private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombre";
 private static final String TAG_ADD ="telefono";
 JSONArray peoples = null;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;
 ListView list;

Handler myHandler = new Handler();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    /// AQUI REFRESCO LA LISTA ENTOCES SI YO INGRESO UN DATO NUEVO EN LA BASE DE DATOS ESTE SE MEUSTRA
    //EL PROBLEMA ES QUE EL SCROLL BAR SUBE CADA 10 SEGUNDOS
    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            getData();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    }, 0);

}

   // METODO QUE MUESTRA LA LISTA O LA MATRIZ
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                VerA.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


///METODO QUE EXTRAE LOS DATOS DE EL JASON PHP
public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://tuescuelanoticias.x10.mx/selectAllJSON.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

 }

}
```

Comment: uhmmm... si lo que quieres es que la parte de la vista se recargue parcialmente mira de hacer llamadas `ajax`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes agregar otra lista de ArrayList> temporal para almacenar el contenido de tu lista anterior y después de la llamada comparar el tamaño de la lista si es mayor significa que hubo cambios y por lo tanto hay que actualizar tu tabla (ListView), en caso contrario no requiere actualización; otra posibilidad es en tu web service mandar una propiedad "count" con la cantidad de datos que se envia y al obtener la respuesta del servidor unicamente verificar si la cantidad es distinta y actualizar la lista, esto ahorraria la iteración de toda la lista para comprobar el tamaño de las listas 
NOTA: esto solo actualizará cuando se hayan agregado o eliminado campos.

Código modificado:

```
    public class VerA extends ActionBarActivity {

    String myJSON;
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombre";
    private static final String TAG_ADD ="telefono";
    JSONArray peoples = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> personListTemp;
    ListView list;

    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
      personListTemp = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

/// AQUI REFRESCO LA LISTA ENTOCES SI YO INGRESO UN DATO NUEVO EN LA BASE DE DATOS ESTE SE MEUSTRA
//EL PROBLEMA ES QUE EL SCROLL BAR SUBE CADA 10 SEGUNDOS
myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        getData();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
}, 0);

}

  // METODO QUE MUESTRA LA LISTA O LA MATRIZ
  protected void showList(){
     try {
     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
     peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

    for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
        JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

        HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

        persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
        persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
        persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

        personList.add(persons);
    }

if(personList.size() != personListTemp.size() ){
        personListTemp = personList;
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                VerA.this, personListTemp, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
        );
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}


///METODO QUE EXTRAE LOS DATOS DE EL JASON PHP
public void getData(){

class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new       BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://tuescuelanoticias.x10.mx/selectAllJSON.php");

        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        myJSON=result;
        showList();
    }
}
GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
g.execute();
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

}
```

Comment: gracias, probare ambas soluciones y comento en caso de que me atore en algo XD

Comment: Muchas gracias, como decimos en Mexico eres un perron, funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

Que tal, entiendo que la respuesta de @AngelRuizC te ha venido de maravilla. Pero revisando tu código he notado algunas cosas que me llaman la atención.
Tu consulta al servidor es para listar una serie de elementos en algún lugar, es decir un `GET` tal como lo estandariza el protocolo HTTP; pero noto en tu fragmento de código que la consulta al server la realizas a través de un `HttpPost`
Te recomendaría que para este tipo de procesos (procesos HHTP GET/POST/etc.) te crearas una clase que tenga esos métodos que son fácilmente reutilizables, por ejemplo para realizar un `GET` a cualquier servidor puedes tener una función como esta:

```
public static InputStream getJsonFromServer(String _url) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(_url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        return urlConnection.getInputStream();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Supongamos que la clase de utilidades se llama ConexionesHttp, simplificarías tu código a lo siguiente, en la llamada al PHP

```
InputStream jsonStream = ConexionesHttp.getJsonFromServer("http://tuescuelanoticias.x10.mx/selectAllJSON.php");
```

Luego un `InputStream` puede ser parseado a `String` de la siguiente manera

```
 String jsonStr = new Scanner(jsonStream , "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

De esta manera cada vez que necesites realizar una consulta http en otro punto no tienes que reescribirla.
Espero te ayude saludos!

Comment: Gracias @Rosendo Ropher, se me complica comprender, soy muy nuevo en esto, pero probare lo que me comenta, gracias

Comment: también quisiera comentarles que la app manda un error de "se ha detenido la aplicación" en el momento que deja de haber Internet o datos, como podría solucionar esto

Comment: Implementa en tu código sentencias try/catch, favorablemente en los lugares en los que el código puede fallar debido a problemas de conexión o cosas como esas. En el Logcat puedes ver específicamente cuál es la clase que está generando la falla y cuál es la línea. Revisa y nos comentas. Saludos.